# IIS 7.5 memory usage of worker process

Tags: asp.net, iis, iis-7.5, application-pool, worker-process

There are lot of discussion regarding high memory consumption of worker process.
I have no Idea what is high.

I do have a ASP.net web application which consumes around 2500 MB, is this high?

[IIS Worker Process Usage](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IUV4C.jpg)

Details:

- Kendo UI
- Nhibernate
- List item
- JSON

30.000 records will be shown in a Kendo UI Grind, paging is active.
Data will be updated every 30 seconds
Furthermore 6 widgets will be updated frequently (10 sec.)

The memory usage of 2500 MB comes up by one user interaction.

Result of DebugDiagnostic:
[DebugDiagAnalysis](http://www.file-upload.net/download-11676416/DebugDiagAnalysis.pdf.html)

Comment: A worker process of an application pool can hold multiple web apps. So discussing the memory footprint without putting everything into consideration is not professional at all and nobody would throw a number to you easily. Learn a profiling tool and let it show you what's in the memory. Then you might tell whether there is something wrong.

Comment: I am now running Debug Diagnostics Tool to get more information. It’s not clear for me whether it’s the usual process of IIS to reserve memory and it’s normal that the usage goes up for a certain time.
Anyway I will wait for the result of the Diagnostics Tool.

Comment: Debug Diagnostics is not a profiler. What you get from DebugDiag's report requires much more experience to interpret. JetBrains dotMemory or other equivalent tools are recommended. Even Visual Studio 2015 has the memory profiler builtin.

Comment: I am now trying dotMemory. have uploaded the result of DebugDiag's